# Facebook Image.. Resize, Crop and keep Ratio

Tags: html, css, facebook, image

Im trying to do **Facebook cards**... But im lost with image, cause i dont have any ideas how to create the image...

I need image **1200x627**px.. do that responsive and keep ratio **1.91:1** ..
So for example i have image **1620x900**px so i wanna resize it a crop it to **1200x627**px and be responsive with a image holder.

I tried a lot of plugins but they are didnt work like what i want...

### Image is 1200x1200px

```css
.card-content {max-width: 1200px; max-height: 627px;}
#content-img {width: 100%; max-height: 627px;}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="card-content">
 <img id="content-img" src="images/galaxy.jpg">
</div>
```

Website example : [enter here](http://fanbooster.com/fbsizes/)

Comment: You are resizing the image using css? That will not work. Facebook will download the image it self

Comment: So what should i use PHP or its gonna work with JQ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

Ok i solved this by calculate PADDING for the ratio 1.91 (like a facebook image card)

**How to calculate:**

> - if u have image for example what u need (for me: 1200x627px) just simple way:
> - need a ratio 1:1.91 so : `1/1.91 * 100 = 52.356 %`
> - so i set `padding:52.356% 0 0 0` and there is it responsive image with that ratio
> - **but don't forget these:** ( whole sample for me)

```
.foo { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; position: relative; overflow: hidden; padding: 52.356% 0 0 0; }
.foo img { display: block; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
```